# Converting NSString to NSdate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

I want to convert NSString to NSDate.

The issue is I am reading the exif information from image which is giving a NSString value.
Now I want to convert this NSString  to NSDate

I have tried below

```
      NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingAllTypes error:&error];
      NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:datestring
                                     options:0
                                       range:NSMakeRange(0, [datestring length])];


    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
       if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeDate) {
           dateObj =  [match date];
           break;
    }
}
```

================

The format that I am seeing in exif is  2010:05:27 17:48:42+04:00

Note:- Is there any method that can take any NSString format and give the NSDate object

### Edit

In NSDateformatter we have to pass a given format type. Can we have a method than can determine the Date format from the string in runtime as the string might have some different format depending on localization or camera type.

Comment: You need a `NSDateFormatter` for this, not a `NSDataDetector`. About half the questions on Stack Overflow regarding iOS are a matter of parsing dates, you should find easily.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best would be if you could create a class just for manipulating with Dates, so I will prefer to create a method like that using NSDateForamatter:

```
+ (NSDate *)getDateFromStringDate:(NSString *)stringDate {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssZ"];
    return [dateFormat dateFromString:stringDate]; 
}
```

There you can set date format which you have.
Hope that will help.

Answer (score 1):

As @Cyrille said, you have to use a `NSDateFormatter`:

```
NSString *myString = @"2010:05:27 17:48:42+0400";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ssZZZ"];

NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myString];
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSDateFormatter`: is the best way to convert `NSString` into `NSDate`

```
NSString *yourString = @"2016:10:13 17:48:42+0400";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ssZZZ"];

NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:yourString];
```